# Using Magento to track inventory for two separate stores

Tags: magento, inventory

I recently found the following add-on: http://innoexts.com/store-view-pricing/

And while it is great that I’m able to separate prices by store view, I also want to keep track of stock on a store view basis.

Here’s the scenario.

I’m currently selling collectible cards on my site for different games. (Magic: The Gathering, Universal Fighting System, etc.)

What I would like to do is have the same inventory appear on two different websites:

- Buy (where customers can BUY the cards from me)
- Sell (where customers will SELL their cards to me)

I know that I will need to set up either a separate website/store view under Magento’s backend. That’s fine. I also know that I will need to configure special payment modules in the backend (because people shouldn’t be paying me to sell their cards). But what I’m mostly looking for is guidance on how to set these two up.

The inventory (for the most part) will be shared between the two sites (with the exceptions of products I’m only interested in selling).

Can anyone help? I've tried to research inventory and the separate stores bit but to no avail.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You say first that you want to keep track of stock on a store view basis, but then you say that you want stock to be SHARED between the two stores. Which is it? Magento's inventory is a global product attribute, so it is shared between stores and websites. If you DON'T want to share stock levels, then you need to create separate products for buying and selling, with different SKUs.

Comment: See I figured that it were possible for me not to have to create two sets of inventory SKU's for this. Either through some manipulation of the core coding much like how the pricing module does. But I suppose dumping the inventory to an export file and changing the "_store" column will accomplish this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think possibly what you're looking for is a "Marketplace" type extension, maybe similar to the [Unirgy Dropship extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/unirgy-dropship.html), which allows you to have sellers add their products to the site (and fulfill them as well).

This would probably be a better model than having a seller go through a modified "checkout" flow with a customized payment gateway module in order for them to add their catalog to the site.